# MacOSのコマンドラインで、悪意のあるプロセスを特定する方法

Tags: macos, security

アンチウイルスソフトなどで、マルウェアや、悪意のあるプロセスなどを特定することができると思いますが、これをOSSを使って、コマンドラインでやる方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/)というクロスプラットフォームのアンチウィルスソフトならコマンドラインからの操作もできます。mac版はbrewでも提供されていたと思います。
私も昔使ったことがあるだけで、現在どこまでお望みの機能が含まれているかは把握していません。Webで検索すると、いろいろ使い方のヒントになるサイトがヒットしましたので、調べてみてはいかがでしょうか。